# Solving system of first order linear differential equations

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the system:
\begin{align}
y' &= az - by\\
z' &= cw(t) - dz
\end{align}
Assume all coefficients $a,b,c,d$ are positive. **My question**: is it possible to solve for the general forms of $z(t)$ and $y(t)$, then plug in to obtain the final answer?

Specifically, I have:
\begin{align}
z(t) &= e^{-dt}\left(c\int_0^t e^{ds}w(s)ds + c_1\right)\\
y(t) &= e^{-bt}\left(a\int_0^t e^{bs}z(s)ds + c_2\right)
\end{align}

Then plug in $z(t)$ into equation for $y(t)$ to obtain:
\begin{align}
y(t) &= e^{-bt}\left(a\int_0^t e^{b\xi} \left[e^{-ds}\left(c\int_0^\xi e^{ds}w(s)ds + c_1\right)\right]d\xi + c_2\right)\\
&= ae^{-bt}\int_0^t\int_0^\xi ce^{(b-d)\xi}e^{ds}w(s)dsd\xi + c_2e^{-bt}.
\end{align}

Comment: Yes. It is a triangular system. The last DE does not depend on the first so we can solve it first and then after substituting, solve for $y(t)$.

Comment: @Cesareo Thank you! I just need to confirm this.